# Use a request with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-xml

I've this LINQ to XML request which retrieve all songs by artist ID :

```
  var query = from c in loaded.Descendants("artist")
                    where c.Attribute("Id").Value.Equals("1")
                    from s in c.Descendants("song")
                    select s.Attribute("path").Value.ToList();
```

When I'm trying to add the result in my ListBox like this :

```
foreach (string track in query)
        {
            myList.Items.Add(track);
        }
```

I got this error :

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

How to add properly my result in my ListBox ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of your use of `ToList()` you're returning an enumerable of lists.

When you try to iterate over the enumerable collection your code tries to convert a list to a char which it cannot do.

Change your code to:

```
  var query = from c in loaded.Descendants("artist")
                    where c.Attribute("Id").Value.Equals("1")
                    from s in c.Descendants("song")
                    select s.Attribute("path").Value
```

If you don't want to make use of the lazy loading feature of an IEnumerable you can convert the whole result set to a list.

Comment: Also be aware that using `s.Attribute("path").Value` can be a bit dangerous, unless you're absolutely certain that the attribute `path` never will be missing in the xml. If you're not certain use `(string)s.Attribute("path")`, which will return string.Empty, if the attribute is missing in the xml. [See MSDN for further explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ToList()` over whole query, not only on "path" attribute value:

```
var query = (from c in loaded.Descendants("artist")
                    where c.Attribute("Id").Value.Equals("1")
                    from s in c.Descendants("song")
                    select s.Attribute("path").Value).ToList();
```

or ship it so the query results will be evaluated when they are needed.